# What's the most concise way to refer to this shape?

Tags: geometry, terminology

What would you call this shape?
[image: shape]

Not the shape in green, I mean the entire object.

Comment: How about "Figure 1"?  :)

Comment: I would call it a section of a cylinder given by two planes, but that is just me.  Maybe there is a more specific name.

Comment: A [rose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(topology)). - Only four letters!

Comment: @Pierre-Yves:  I think the vertical line on the right is to indicate that the "shape" in question is the cylindrical section (the volume), not the curve that is the union of the two circles.

Comment: Dear @Cam: I think you're right, but I'll leave the comment, because I had fun writing it... Thanks anyway! - I upvoted your comment: LOL

Comment: Agreed, I'm hardly in a position to critique anyone else's response.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [cylindrical segment or truncated cylinder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalSegment.html)
or perhaps more specifically a [cylindrical wedge](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalWedge.html).

Answer (score 3):

Cylindrical wedge: see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalWedge.html

Comment: This is the special case where $a=0$ and $b=2R$.